# una ayuda con este problema funcion que se le ingrese un carácter y determine si es una letra o número u otro carácter que no sea ni letra o número

Tags: c++, c, funciones, caracteres

el prototipo de la funcion es

```
Resultado FuncionCaracter( char car );
```

el problema dice que no puedo utilizar las funciones de c

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a stackoverflow! En esta comunidad no hacemos tareas ni deberes, sino, **resolvemos dudas especificas**. Así que te invito a leer esto: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), de lo contrario, la pregunta terminará cerrada. Una recomendación por mi parte, sería que agregues en la pregunta el código que tengas hecho y después a partir de ese código, elaboras la duda.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando un casteo a `int` puedes convertir tu caracter a su valor correspondiente de la tabla ASCII , de modo que puedes verificar entre que valores esta y por ende saber si es un número, letra o símbolo.

```
void isA(char c){
    int number = int(c);

    if(number >= 48 and number <= 57)
        cout << c << " is a number\n";
    else if(number >= 65 and number <= 90 or number >= 97 and number <= 122)
        cout << c << " is a letter\n";
    else
        cout << c << " is a symbol\n";
}
```

Comment: La comunidad no suele responder a preguntas mal formuladas. En este caso, el OP ni siquiera ha definido un problema con respecto al código que tenga hecho.